# How to detect which Window was selected when using Aero peek

Tags: wpf, aero, aero-peek

I am not even sure how to ask this question...

I have a WPF app with a main window in full screen. It launches new windows in full screen and makes them a child of the main window upon some user interactions. If the user's machine only has a single monitor this child window is supposed to be the focus until closed. However, I have found that using Windows Aero if the user hovers over my application's taskbar icon a preview of both windows appear. This in itself is not an issue except if you try to select the main window of the app nothing happens because the child window is always on top but the peek functionality gives the illusion that the user can switch to the main window and it looks like a bug.

I would like to detect which window the user is selecting and, if it is the main window, simply close the child window. Alternatively I would like Aero to stop showing multiple windows if only one will work.

Anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question.